# How to pass results of computations to a function definition?

Tags: function-construction, parametric-functions

Here is the following code that works,

```
 F[{x_,y_,z_}]:={16(y-x), x(45-z)-y, x*y-4z);
 x = Array[a,3];
 F[x]
```

and the answer is,

```
 {16(-a[1] + a[2]) , -a[2] + a1(45-a[3]) , a[1]a[2] - 4a[3] }
```

Here is my problem.  I have some complicated and long equation to be evaluated therefore I cannot put it in a function right away.  I have to evaluate it first and use the results as a function definition.  For example,

```
  result1= 16(y-x);
  result2= x(45-z)-y;
  result3= x*y-4z;
  F[{x_,y_,z_}]:={result1, result2, result3};
  x = Array[a,3];
  F[x]
```

does not give me the same result as in the previous code.  I've tried treating result1 as function but that does not work either.

Comment: Change `SetDelayed` to `Set`. (Be sure to first `ClearAll[F, x, y, z]`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either of the following

```
result1 = 16 (y - x);
result2 = x (45 - z) - y;
result3 = x*y - 4 z;
F[{x_, y_, z_}] := Evaluate[{result1, result2, result3}];
x = Array[a, 3];
F[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
result1 = 16 (y - x);
result2 = x (45 - z) - y;
result3 = x*y - 4 z;
F[{x_, y_, z_}] = {result1, result2, result3};
x = Array[a, 3];
F[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both give same result you showed.

But I would not do either one. Why not write the function so that it does the computation inside as well?  accessing global context from inside a function is not a good thing to do and you'll soon start seeing problems once your code gets larger.

btw, you type `{..)` in your code. I assumed this was a copy/paste issue.

Comment: thanks for great answer and most of all the last advice.  I understand the implications.  But I will try simple approach.  If it creates complication (numerical?) I'll do the last resort (your advice) but that means lots of changes in code.